# Getting a web service and using android to consume them?

Tags: c#, android, web-services, wcf

I have been looking up on youtube regarding Web Services being consume using android. Most of the video are all 1 or 2 years old. Is this doing outdated? is there a better way to do this? currently i am in a company and i was assign to have a android version of their webservice.

I was told to create the service with sql using Visual studio.
Create the android UI and using the services to pull the data.

Am i doing it right?

What is the better or ideal way of going about this?

Should i add JavaScript or something like that?

I have been looking at RESTful , Soap , Json and Wcf. But what is the best way to go if i have to start everything from scratch?

-Programs/System that i am using.

- Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web
- SQL server
- IIS express
- Android Studio

*I was told to only user framework 4.0 for Visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WCF (SOAP), WCF (RESTful) or WebApi to create a service, both has it's own advantages and disadvantages. You may want to take some time to look at your requirement and then decide what type of service you want to develop. SOAP uses a more complicated messaging pattern using XML, where as REST uses the standard HTTP protocol and methods to communicate and transfer data. But if you are planning consume this service across of variety of applications like mobile, web, desktop, client side script interaction etc, you may consider developing the service as a RESTful. More information on SOAP and RESTful and for detailed understanding you may refer to this link 
[Understanding SOAP and RESTful](http://blog.smartbear.com/apis/understanding-soap-and-rest-basics/)

Comment: it is a stock taking app, so displaying of records, and adding records will be needed that is all. I believe base on that REST will be better right? if that is the case WCF or WebApi is better?

Comment: WebApi would be a better option for REST as it is an ideal platform to build REST services and uses MVC pattern.

Comment: Thank you but is it possible to explain a little more indepth about MVC and Webapi, what i read about is to use webApi or MVC. or am i reading the wrong stuff...

Comment: MVC is just a type of design pattern and you need to use this design pattern to create WebAPI. You can refer to the below link on how to create a WebAPI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api