# What is the advantage of using Web API in wpf?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I need to calling our C# Methods from another server to perform some Action. I use C# in both servers. One is our Service Application, another one is a WPF application where I consume my Service.

Prefer I use a WCF or WebAPI service for Service Application?
Most People prefer to use Web Api, but web doesn't expose metadata for creating proxy by service.

which one is simple and better choose?

Comment: WCF (with code generation) is a little easier to use, but not by much. If you ever want to add other clients (JavaScript,  Android, iOS) then better use WebAPI.

Comment: The way this is phrased it's opinion based.  You'll find a lot of material out there if you just search for "SOAP vs REST", and even "WebHttpBinding vs WebAPI".  There are other considerations, but that's probably the biggest one.

Comment: I don't want do add other client, Why Web Api is better ?

Comment: Web API uses basic HTTP and the payload is less compared to WCF which uses SOAP. So it is well suited for clients that have low bandwidth. WCF is very versatile and is a great way to build secure service. If you don't need the features that WCF provided then Web API is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

You may use either WCF or WebAPI, if multiple platforms (Mobile, Web, Other Service) are going to interact with your service, then I would recommend Web API, otherwise you may use WCF. Similar discussion has already happened in another question, please refer this link, hope this will be useful
[Getting a web service and using android to consume them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335415/getting-a-web-service-and-using-android-to-consume-them/42336245#42336245)

Comment: You can do REST over WCF.  And you can certainly do SOAP based communication using other platforms.

Comment: @DanField, any reason the answer was down voted? I agree you can do rest over WCF, but the rest can also be achieved with WCF. How you want to implement a solution is based on the project complexity, personal choice and infrastructure available.

Comment: Because you're making an opinion based recommendation and not really providing much detail as to why.  It's not even necessarily that you're wrong, but that you're feeding into an opinion based question with an opinion based answer that won't really help future readers as much.